# Bind a QIcon provided by a class derived from QAbstractListModel to QML Image

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qabstractitemmodel

I try to bind a QIcon provided by a class derived from QAbstractListModel to QML Image like this:

```
Component {
    id: myDelegate
    //...
            Column {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                spacing: 5

                Image {
                    source: model.DecorationRole
                }

                Text {
                    text: model.DisplayRole
    //...
}
```

But this results in  this error:

> Unable to assign QIcon to QUrl

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You can not assign a `QIcon` as a source of a QML `Image`.

What you need to do is choose a custom URL format for your icons, e.g.

```
images://myicons/<icon_id>
```

This string is what you set as a URL for `Image.source`.

Now you create and register an imageprovider, that delivers the icon when you send the requested URL from QML:

- Create a subclass of `QQuickImageProvider`, e.g. `MyIconProvider`
- Overwrite the function `requestPixmap` that takes the `id` as and argument and returns pixel data

Then you register the image provider in your `main.cpp`

```
MyIconProvider *mip = new MyIconProvider();
engine.addImageProvider("myicons", mip);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how to return the pixel data (which obviously have to come from my model)?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out this solution. It works, but any suggestions or improvements are very welcome.

**ImageProvider.h**

```
class ImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{
    public:
        explicit ImageProvider(myModel *myModel);
        QPixmap requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize);

    signals:

    public slots:

    private:
        myModel *m_myModel;
};
```

**ImageProvider.cpp**

```
ImageProvider::ImageProvider(myModel *myModel) :
    QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Pixmap),
    m_myModel(myModel)
{
}

QPixmap ImageProvider::requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    QModelIndex index;
    bool foundId = false;

    for(int row = 0; row < m_myModel->rowCount(); row++)
    {
        index = m_myModel->index(row, 0);
        QString name = QVariant(m_myModel->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole)).toString();

        if(name == id)
        {
            foundId = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!foundId)
        return QPixmap();

    QIcon icon = m_myModel->data(index, Qt::DecorationRole).value<QIcon>();

    QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(128,128);

    return pixmap;
}
```

**register imageProvider...**

```
ImageProvider *imageProvider = new ImageProvider(myModel);
view->engine()->addImageProvider(QLatin1String("provider"), imageProvider);
```

**main.qml**

```
Component {
    id: myDelegate
    //...
            Column {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                spacing: 5

                Image {
                    source: "image://provider/" + model.DisplayRole
                }

                Text {
                    text: model.DisplayRole
    //...
}
```